# Передача файлов по scp между серверами

Tags: c#, scp

Нужно организовать передачу данных от одного удаленного сервера к другому, без скачивания на мой комп. Это делается через scp, но я не нашел ни одной либы которая поддерживает этого. Может быть кто нить сталкивался с этим?

Comment: А чем winscp не подходит? Я всегда им пользуюсь.

Comment: между двумя удаленными системами может он слать?

Comment: да ты хоть curl-ом -  http(s)-запросом можешь файлы пересылать, зачем тебе scp

Answer (score 1):

## Что вам мешает зайти с помощью WinSCP по SSH и от имени сервера сделать так, как описано ниже или воспользоваться Putty?

Копируем файл **.bash_history** с первого сервера, из домашней директории - в домашнюю директорию второго и сразу меняем ему имя и расширение на **bash_history.log** Потребуется ввести два раза пароли от первого сервере и от второго. Естественно ввод не будет отображаться в терминале.

> *Если имеется активное SSH соединение, то разорвите его командой* **`exit`**

```
$ scp user@remote_1.ru:~/.bash_history user@remote_2.ru:~/bash_history.log
```

SCP (Secure CoPy) - программа для удаленного копирования фалов по сети между хостами.
Она использует SSH для передачи данных, ту же аутентификацию и те же меры безопасности, что и SSH.
Во время копирования исходного фала в файл назначения, который уже существует, SCP перезаписывает файл назначения.

---

***Если файл назначения еще не существует, тогда создается пустой файл, ему задается имя файла назначения и уже в него записывается содержимое копируемого файла!!!***

Пример 1 : Копируем файл "file.txt" из удаленного сервера на
   локальный компьютер.

`$ scp user@remote.host:file.txt /some/local/directory`

Пример 2 : Копируем файл "file.txt" с локального компьютера на
   удаленный сервер.

`$ scp file.txt user@remote.host:/some/remote/directory`

Пример 3 : Копируем папку "dir1" с локального хоста в директорию
   "dir2" на удаленном хосте.

`$ scp -r dir1 user@remote.host:/some/remote/directory/dir2`

Пример 4 : Копируем файл "file.txt" с одного удаленного сервера "remote.host1"
на другой удаленный сервер "remote.host2".

```
$ scp user@remote.host1:/directory/file.txt user@remote.host2:/some/directory/
```

Пример 5 : Копируем файлы "file1.txt" и "file2.txt" с локального компьютера в
Ваш домашний каталог на удаленном сервере.

```
$ scp file1.txt file2.txt user@remote.host:~
```

Пример 6 : Копируем файл "file.txt" с локального хоста на удаленный хост, используя порт 2222.

```
$ scp -P 2222 file.txt user@remote.host:/some/remote/directory
```

Пример 7 : Копируем файл "file.txt" с локального компьютера в Ваш домашний каталог на удаленном сервере.
Сохраняем время изменения и время доступа и права копируемого фала.

```
$ scp -p file.txt user@remote.host:~
```

Пример 8 : Копируем файл "file.txt" с локального компьютера в Ваш домашний каталог на удаленном сервере.
Увеличиваем скорость работы SCP изменяя алгоритм шифрования с AES-128 (по умолчанию) на Blowfish.

```
$ scp -c blowfish file.txt user@remote.host:~
```

Пример 9 : Копируем файл "file.txt" с локального компьютера в Ваш домашний каталог на удаленном сервере.
Ограничиваем ширину канала используемого командой SCP до 100 Kbit/s.

```
$ scp -l 100 file.txt user@remote.host:~
```

Пример 10 : Копируем несколько файлов с удаленного хост в текущую директорию на Вашем локальном хосте.

```
$ scp user@remote.host:~/\{file1,file2,file3\} .
```

[Взято отсюда](http://www.shellhacks.com/ru/10-Primerov-Kopirovanie-faylov-cherez-SSH)

P.S. Если на принимающей стороне стоит rsync, то можно воспользоваться им:

```
rsync -azP user@remote.host1:~/ user@remote.host2:~/
```

- рекурсивно с докачкой, копированием прав и сжатием на лету перекачает домашнюю директорию с одного сервера на другой.